# managedObjectContext returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have created a helper class that only contains methods for retrieving data from Core Data and Parse, `DataService.swift`

Within that class, I have (amongst more of it) the following code:

```
func getUserStoreItems(itemSkuArray: [String]) {
        (...)


        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Book")

        do {
            let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            let bookListNSManagedObject = results as! [NSManagedObject]
            for bookNSManagedObject in bookListNSManagedObject {
                print("Here is the Core Data \(bookNSManagedObject)")
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

    }
```

However, this throws a

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

on

```
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectcontext
```

Here is managedObjectContext declaration:

```
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The relevant code would be the code that creates the managedObjectContext in the AppDelegate class.

Comment: A good trouble shooting step might be to put a breakpoint in that block of code that creates the managedObjectContext and make sure it's executing and returning a reasonable value.

Comment: @CharlesA. I have done that, and managedObjectContext is nil

Answer (score 0):

`delegate` is an optional variable. I expect you just didn't set a delegate.

```
unowned(unsafe) var delegate: UIApplicationDelegate?
```

Try to check the delegate before use:

```
if let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate {
     // use appDelegate
}
```

Comment: When i cmd+click `.delegate` that is what I get, yes. Sorry I don't understand what you're suggesting I do @Arsen

Comment: The AppDelegate is there, the line that fails is `appDelegate.managedObjectContext`. I checked if it exists like your edit says and it's still `appDelegate.managedObjectContext` that causes the crash.   @Arsen